# Static classes being initialised on import. How does python 2 initialise static classes on import

Tags: python, class, import, static

I am trying to introduce python 3 support for the package [mime](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mime) and the code is doing something I have never seen before.

There is a class `Types()` that is used in the package as a static class.

```
class Types(with_metaclass(ItemMeta, object)): # I changed this for 2-3 compatibility

    type_variants = defaultdict(list)
    extension_index = defaultdict(list)

    # __metaclass__ = ItemMeta # unnessecary now

    def __init__(self, data_version=None):
        self.data_version = data_version
```

The `type_variants` defaultdict is what is getting filled in python 2 but not in 3.

It very much seems to be getting filled by this class when is in a different file called `mime_types.py`.

```
class MIMETypes(object):
    _types = Types(VERSION)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<MIMETypes version:%s>' % VERSION

    @classmethod
    def load_from_file(cls, type_file):
        data = open(type_file).read()
        data = data.split('\n')
        mime_types = Types()
        for index, line in enumerate(data):
            item = line.strip()
            if not item:
                continue
            try:
                ret = TEXT_FORMAT_RE.match(item).groups()
            except Exception as e:
                __parsing_error(type_file, index, line, e)

            (unregistered, obsolete, platform, mediatype, subtype, extensions,
             encoding, urls, docs, comment) = ret
            if mediatype is None:
                if comment is None:
                    __parsing_error(type_file, index, line, RuntimeError)
                continue
            extensions = extensions and extensions.split(',') or []
            urls = urls and urls.split(',') or []
            mime_type = Type('%s/%s' % (mediatype, subtype))
            mime_type.extensions = extensions
            ...
            mime_type.url = urls
            mime_types.add(mime_type) # instance of Type() is being filled?
        return mime_types
```

The function `startup()` is being run whenever `mime_types.py` is imported and it does this.

```
def startup():
    global STARTUP
    if STARTUP:
        type_files = glob(join(DIR, 'types', '*'))
        type_files.sort()
        for type_file in type_files:
            MIMETypes.load_from_file(type_file) # class method is filling Types?
    STARTUP = False
```

This all seems pretty weird to me. The `MIMETypes` class first creates an instance of `Types()` on the first line. `_types = Types(VERSION)`. It then seems to do nothing with this instance and only use the `mime_types` instance created in the `load_from_file()` class method. `mime_types = Types()`.

This sort of thing vaguely reminds me of javascript class construction. How is the instance `mime_types` filling `Types.type_variants` so that when it is imported like this.

`from mime import Type, Types`

The class's `type_variants` defaultdict can be used. And why isn't this working in python 3?

EDIT:

Adding extra code to show how `type_variants` is filled

```
(In "Types" Class)
@classmethod
def add_type_variant(cls, mime_type):
    cls.type_veriants[mime_type.simplified].append(mime_type)

@classmethod
def add(cls, *types):
    for mime_type in types:
        if isinstance(mime_type, Types):
            cls.add(*mime_type.defined_types())
        else:
            mts = cls.type_veriants.get(mime_type.simplified)
            if mts and mime_type in mts:
                Warning('Type %s already registered as a variant of %s.',
                        mime_type, mime_type.simplified)
            cls.add_type_variant(mime_type)
            cls.index_extensions(mime_type)
```

You can see that `MIMETypes` uses the `add()` classmethod.

Comment: The code you present contains no references to any variable named `type_variants` except for the original declaration.  So how can it possibly get modified or "filled" or accessed in any way in this code?  This question applies regardless of the Python version.  In the Python2 case it must be getting filled somewhere else.  Does your listing leave out something important?

Comment: @PaulCornelius: Yes I did leave out the class methods that interact with the `type_variants` dict. `MIMETypes` has the method that calls `add()` to fill the dictionary.

Comment: What do you mean by "static class"? That might mean something in other languages (with the meaning depending on the language), but in Python, that adjective cannot be applied to that noun.

Comment: @user2357112 just that the class is used without being instantiated. The code does something like `Types['something']` rather than `types = Types()` and then `types['something']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without posting more of your code, it's hard to say.  I will say that I was able to get that package ported to Python 3 with only a few changes (print statement -> function, `basestring` -> `str`, adding a dot before same-package imports, and a really ugly hack to compensate for their love of `cmp`:

```
def cmp(x,y): 
    if isinstance(x, Type): return x.__cmp__(y)
    if isinstance(y, Type): return y.__cmp__(x) * -1
    return 0 if x == y else (1 if x > y else -1)
```

Note, I'm not even sure this is correct.

Then

```
import mime
print(mime.Types.type_veriants)    # sic
```

printed out a 1590 entry `defaultdict`.

---

Regarding your question about `MIMETypes._types` not being used, I agree, it's not.

Regarding your question about *how* the dictionary is being populated, it's quite simple, and you've identified most of it.

```
import mime
```

Imports the package's `__init__.py` which contains the line:

```
from .mime_types import MIMETypes, VERSION
```

And `mime_types.py` includes the lines:

```
def startup():
    global STARTUP
    if STARTUP:
        type_files = glob(join(DIR, 'types', '*'))
        type_files.sort()
        for type_file in type_files:
            MIMETypes.load_from_file(type_file)
    STARTUP = False

startup()
```

And `MIMETypes.load_from_file()` has the lines:

```
mime_types = Types()
#...
for ... in ...:
    mime_types.add(mime_type)
```

And `Types.add():` has the line:

```
cls.add_type_variant(mime_type)
```

And that classmethod contains:

```
cls.type_veriants[mime_type.simplified].append(mime_type)
```

Comment: Yeah I did the same sort of hacks to port over to python 3. It was the unittests that were failing because of the empty defaultdict. I'll have to check out whether just importing it and ignoring the unittests is fine.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Regarding your edit, I can see how the dict is filled, but how come filling the instance *also* fills the static Class. And I still don't understand why it's not working in python 3 for me

Comment: Also what did you do port the project? Did you pip install the package and then edit it or did you download it from Github and edit it?

Comment: In classmethods, the first argument the class.  The same thing you'd get if you did `type(<an instance>)` or `<class name>`.  This is different from regular / non-classmethods where the first argument is the instance.  So in `Types.add()`, `cls.add_type_variant()` is the same as typing `Types.add_class_variant()` and inside that classmethod, `cls.type_veriants[...].append()` is the same as `Types.type_veriants[...].append()`.

Comment: @thundergolfer I downloaded the source tarball from the PyPy link you posted.

Comment: Thanks mate, I will try a do only the changes you did and see if the package works on 2 and 3 and tests pass

Comment: The tests definitely won't pass, at least they didn't for me.  It looks like my `__cmp__` hack was a little inadequate.  Anyway, here's a gist of the few hacks I did do, if that helps: [Gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/92ad3584dbcfd13dcaa90961b6df65fa)

Comment: Thanks heaps. I think I understand about the classmethod updating now. Because the classmethod has a reference to `cls` and not `self`, calling the method on the 'instance' `mimetypes` will still update the class itself.

Comment: @thundergolfer, yep, exactly -- that's why it's convention to name the first argument of classmethods `cls` (it could be named anything).  `mimetypes` *is* a full-blown instance, but they don't really use it like one.